# How to dynamically generate secret tokens in Rails 4.1 with secrets.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4

New to rails. Followed Hartl's tutorial where he uses this code to dynamically generate secret token for config/initializers/secret_token.rb

```
require 'securerandom'

def secure_token
  token_file = Rails.root.join('.secret')
  if File.exist?(token_file)
    # Use the existing token.
    File.read(token_file).chomp
  else
    # Generate a new token and store it in token_file.
    token = SecureRandom.hex(64)
    File.write(token_file, token)
    token
  end
end

SampleApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
```

I'm trying to follow the new Rails 4.1 way by using secrets.yml, and delete the secret_token.rb:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 79c1389c2fadc5a5a1918a5104ab34eb700c

test:
  secret_key_base: fdb4edcde14173d62963705ca4d7876b5307790924

production:
  secret_key_base: 85172605030a8225c083d886d066da2cb4aac1f0
```

But I think you cannot run ruby script like the one in secret_token.rb in a yml file. How would you have rails dynamically generate the secret tokens in secret. How should this be done? What is best practice?

Answer (score 3):

Given a function secret_token whose only job is to generate a new token string each time one's application accesses the secrets.yml file, cookies and most likely other session-like behavior will not work correctly as the secret token changes each call to the function.

The preferred & secure way is to use any old secret key in the secrets.yml file for development and test environments (you can generate a secret string by issuing `rake secret` on the command line), then use an environment variable that your production server knows, so the secrets.yml file looks like:

```
production:
 secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

For example, on Heroku, use `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE="insert key here"` to set the environment variable and there you have it. Don't be afraid to check the secrets.yml file into scm...as long as you haven't saved your production key to the file (and are instead using the environment variable method I just described), checking the file into scm poses no threat.

Comment: The secrets.yml file is, as its name suggest, meant to be a *secret* therefore should not be committed to any repository. That file should also have minimal read rights on Unix servers, so only people with enough rights can initially seed it and then it's supposed to be left untouched, and only useable by the rails app. 
I also used to read the variable from the environment, but I believe it is actually a bad practice. In the end it's just delaying the problem : you would have to secure the environment and/or use something like `dotenv`which is basically doing the same as `secrets.yml`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually run ERB code in YML files. Something like:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= secret_token %>
```

should work (if whatever process reads the YML file can access the secure_token method).

Comment: thanks. but will it work? will <%= secret token %> find the secret_token function in secret_token.rb? the 'upgrade to rails 4.1 guide' says you should delete secret_token.rb. If so, maybe you can put the function in a file called /config/secret_function.rb?

Comment: I would put it in the lib folder. The thing could be a bit tricky, since this file would most likely be evaluated when Rails starts and so even if later a Rails model or controller could access it, at this time it still may fail. You could use the same <% %> (without = then) to include any other file directly in YML though, maybe the best way in this case.

Comment: Thanks. would you mind answering this one as well. It's different, but highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674774/why-would-you-dynamicly-generate-your-secret-token-rb-in-rails