# Why would you dynamicly generate your secret_token.rb in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4

In Hartl's tutorial he rewrites secret_token.rb to dynamicly generate the secret token. Why does he do that? What would the difference be from storing it in the file, as long as you don't version control it?

Hartl's secure_token.rb code:

```
require 'securerandom'

def secure_token
  token_file = Rails.root.join('.secret')
  if File.exist?(token_file)
    # Use the existing token.
    File.read(token_file).chomp
  else
    # Generate a new token and store it in token_file.
    token = SecureRandom.hex(64)
    File.write(token_file, token)
    token
  end
end

SampleApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
```

Comment: Much better idea is to use environment variables. It is much less painful.

Comment: Some hosts (like Heroku) provide read-only environment so this won't work, as file `.secret` will be deleted each deploy, which implies that each time your signed cookies become invalid. Also this code will slow down initialization of your app and is quite strange. Compare it to `App.config.secret_key_base = ENV['SECURE_TOKEN'] 'some_token'`. Now this show exactly what I mean. Also managing environment variables is much easier than this code (and is persistent also).

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier: Can you think of a reason why Hartl included it in his tutorial?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe he doesn't like environment variables? Or he just don't get used to this. Ask him.

Comment: Why don't you ask him?

Comment: When you're deploying your app, this environment variable has to come from somewhere and this is the heart of the problem. On a modern Continuous Delivery system, you're deploying the whole VM and you don't want to store secrets in the VM either. Or generally, on the server, even if it's not a dynamically built VM, i.e. Docker container.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple. With that kind of token generation:

1. You application is ready for deployment on any machine (without worrying about creating secret token file and etc.)
2. And still, you can't possibly get secret token itself even if you have access to codebase (for example if you pushed your app to GitHub).
3. Also, each installation of your application will have a different secret token. It means, for example, that encrypted data from a development machine (for example passwords) will be useless in production application.

However, it is dangerous enough **to show how you generate your secret token**. Tools or libraries you use can be vulnerable at any given point of time.

Comment: Reason 2 would not be right, if you are not version controlling your secure_token.rb. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. As long as you don't version control it - there's no token.

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit.

Comment: @marvelousNinja - `SecureRandom` is secure. Showing that you generated your secure token isn't that unsafe (as `rake secret` do the same).

Comment: I'm not speaking about specific way of generating tokens. Exposing your algorithms just shows how you do things. That's kind of knowledge what attacker always wants to have.