# Questions about upgrading to Rails 4.1.0 and implications to Hartl's sample_app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

Reading through the release notes for Rails 4.1.0, I see that there seems to be some inclusion of/modification to a file `config/secrets.yml` and I'm wondering the effects on the sample_app from Hartl's book...

My questions are:

1. For security best practices, should one add this file to the `.gitignore` file or is Rails handling this by default? If so, can `.secret` be removed from the `.gitignore` file? e.g. [Listing 1.7 .gitignore file](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#code-gitignore)
2. In chapter 3 of Hartl's book, steps are taken to dynamically create the secret token [here](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#code-secret_token). With this new `config/secrets.yml` is there any reason to continue to dynamically create the secret-token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I more or less answer my own question in an answer for someone else's question: [How to dynamicly generate secret tokens in Rails 4.1 with secrets.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673936/how-to-dynamicly-generate-secret-tokens-in-rails-4-1-with-secrets-yml/23439000#23439000)