# How to use secrets.yml for API_KEYS in Rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, capistrano

In one of my recent projects I started out by `.gitignoring` the files containing secrets and environment variables. So the entire project is committed to the repo except the files that contain third party secrets such as that of Stripe, Twitter API or Facebook Graph or internal api_keys, ala the `./config/initializers/secret_token.rb` file.

Now I am at a point where the project is about to go live (excited!) and I need to port all the environment variables on to the production server using Capistrano i.e. `cap production deploy.`

[Edit 4: Yr, 2018]
In case of initializers/secret_token.rb it is clear that Rails 4.1 has a new way of handling [secrets.yml file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml) that pulls in the :secret_key_base value to the production server. Here, I recommend using the [capistrano-secrets-yml](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-secrets-yml) gem which works right out of the box and is dead simple to use.

What is left is the way to carry other secrets like API_KEYS, APP_IDs etc. to the production server without checking any of those into the repo. How to do this, what is the most recommended/securest way or the best practices?

NOTE: I'll be editing the question as it progresses/I get more clarity.

EDIT1: Server is a Ubuntu/Linux VPS on DigitalOcean [Answer to Denise, below].

EDIT2: Can the env_variables/secrets be carried over to the server via secrets.yml? Secret_token for sessions is not the only secret after all! [Answered on Edit3]

EDIT3: Yes! It's possible to send in the API_keys via secrets.yml according to this [blog](http://nycdevshop.com/blog/10). Will share my findings in sometime. :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First rule: DO NOT CHECK-IN `secrets.yml` into the repo.

All right, here's how a `secret.yml` would look:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 6a1ada9d8e377c8fad5e530d6e0a1daa3d17e43ee... 
  # Paste output of $ rake secret here for your dev machine.

test:
  secret_key_base: _your_secret_ as above

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= secure_token %>


  STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY: 'Put your stripe keys for production'
  STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: 'Put actual keys for production here'
  FB_APP_SECRET: 'same as above'
  FB_CALLBACK_URL: 'FB url here'
  FB_CALLBACK_UPDATE_URL: 'FB url here'
  GOOGLE_KEY: 'Put your keys for production'
  GOOGLE_SECRET: 'same as above'
  TWITTER_KEY: 'same as above'
  TWITTER_SECRET: 'same as above'
  TWITTER_USERNAME: 'same as above'
  LINKEDIN_KEY: 'same as above'
  LINKEDIN_SECRET: 'same as above'
```

Note the `secure_token` up there in the `production:` block. On production server I'm using an initializer to [dynamically generate secret_tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673936/how-to-dynamicly-generate-secret-tokens-in-rails-4-1-with-secrets-yml?rq=1) on-the-fly.

> sidenote: be careful about spaces and tabs inside the .yml file. It must be properly formatted and spaced (such as having a space after the ':' symbol).

To set it up on production you could then scp the file directly from your local or use the [capistrano-secrets-yml](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-secrets-yml) gem.

> This will not work. See an updated method as per @OddityOverseer's answer below.

To access the environment variables in your app `environments/production.rb` use:

```
FB_APP_SECRET            = ENV['FB_APP_SECRET']
FB_CALLBACK_URL          = ENV['FB_CALLBACK_URL']
FB_CALLBACK_UPDATE_URL   = ENV['FB_CALLBACK_UPDATE_URL']
GOOGLE_KEY               = ENV['GOOGLE_KEY']
GOOGLE_SECRET            = ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET']
TWITTER_KEY              = ENV['TWITTER_KEY']
TWITTER_SECRET           = ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
TWITTER_USERNAME         = ENV['TWITTER_USERNAME']
LINKEDIN_KEY             = ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY']
LINKEDIN_SECRET          = ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET']
```

---

> UPDATED August-2016:

To access the environment variables in your app `environments/production.rb` use:

```
FB_APP_SECRET            = Rails.application.secrets.FB_APP_SECRET
FB_CALLBACK_URL          = Rails.application.secrets.FB_CALLBACK_URL
FB_CALLBACK_UPDATE_URL   = Rails.application.secrets.FB_CALLBACK_UPDATE_URL
GOOGLE_KEY               = Rails.application.secrets.GOOGLE_KEY
GOOGLE_SECRET            = Rails.application.secrets.GOOGLE_SECRET
TWITTER_KEY              = Rails.application.secrets.TWITTER_KEY
TWITTER_SECRET           = Rails.application.secrets.TWITTER_SECRET
TWITTER_USERNAME         = Rails.application.secrets.TWITTER_USERNAME
LINKEDIN_KEY             = Rails.application.secrets.LINKEDIN_KEY
LINKEDIN_SECRET          = Rails.application.secrets.LINKEDIN_SECRET
```

That's about it.

Comment: The last part (access) didn't work for me. I've used this solution: you can access using Rails.application.secrets.key_name

Answer (score 43):

`Rails.application.secrets.key_name`

Answer (score 8):

One way to do it is to store those secret keys in environment variables. How to set an environment variable is different depending on what operating system you're on. For a linux machine, usually you're editing a .bashrc or .bash_profile file in your home directory and adding a line that looks like:

```
export API_KEYS=apikeygoeshere
```

You'll have to edit the file for whatever user will run rails.

Then in `production.rb`, you can refer to those environment variables as:

```
ENV["API_KEYS"]
```

Another option is to use a ruby gem that essentially takes care of that for you, like figaro. The way it works is that you create another file that you don't check in and figaro takes care of setting them up as environment variables, which you can then refer to in your development.rb/production.rb scripts using the `ENV["API_KEYS"]` above. Because you aren't checking in the file that has all of the environment variables, you'll have to find some way to get that file onto whatever machines are running the code.

Comment: Thanks Denise for leading me to Figaro. Will check it out! Is it also possible to carry these secrets-cum-environment-variables via secrets.yml? Though I did not find any flier doing just that.

Comment: What happens during testing in travis ci? I need to provide my api for the project to work. But it would be exposed. I can't play with environment variables here. So what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is specific to Rails 4.1, but those who upgrade to Rails 5.1 it now includes built in secret generation. Which seems a much better way to handle sensitive data in your rails app.

See: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#encrypted-secrets

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach to deal with different environments would be to:

```sh
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

```yaml
development:
  cloudinary:
    cloud_name: dxe1hjkoi
    api_key: 361019726125669
    api_secret: Cn6tHfSf019278367sZoO083eOI
production:
  cloudinary:
    cloud_name: oiajsu98u
    api_key: 091828812791872
    api_secret: KJS98182kjaksh89721jhS9812j
```

Then use it as:

```rb
Cloudinary.config do |config|
  config.cloud_name = 
    Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :cloudinary, :cloud_name)
  config.api_key = 
    Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :cloudinary, :api_key)
  config.api_secret = 
    Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :cloudinary, :api_secret)
end
```