# Using javascript for Stripe Elements

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How to include my Javascript file into the views?

I have my stripe elements but the fields aren't showing.

It works in the snippet but not in my app...

```js
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('324576895435678976FL1LHd');

// Create an instance of Elements.
// Create an instance of Elements
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '24px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*, label {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#button-element {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #32325d;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 31px;
}

#button-element:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  background-color: #43458b;
}

#form-element {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 120px;
}

label {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#card-errors {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  color: #fa755a;
}

.form-row {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.token {
  color: #32325d;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#stripe-token-handler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 100px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1),
    0 15px 35px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.15),
    0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

#stripe-token-handler.is-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}

/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */


.StripeElement {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}

.ElementsApp, .ElementsApp .InputElement {
  color: #32325d;line-height: 24px;font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;height: 24px;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.ElementsApp:not(.is-autofilled) .InputElement:-webkit-autofill {
  color: #32325d;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #32325d;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement + .Input-placeholder--ie {
  opacity: 1;color: #aab7c4;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;color: #aab7c4;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;color: #aab7c4;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;color: #aab7c4;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;color: #aab7c4;
}
.ElementsApp .InputElement.is-invalid {
  color: #fa755a;
}
.ElementsApp:not(.is-autofilled) .InputElement.is-invalid:-webkit-autofill {
  color: #fa755a;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #fa755a;
}
.ElementsApp.is-invalid .Icon-fill--invalid {
  fill: #fa755a;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="stripejs.js"></script>

    <form id="form-element" action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="card-element">
          Credit or debit card
        </label>
        <div id="card-element">
          <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
        </div>

        <!-- Used to display form errors -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
      </div>

      <button id="button-element">Submit Payment</button>
    </form>
```

if you run the code without the JS, that is what it looks like in my app.  So im not connecting the JS correctly

any suggestions on how I do this the right way?

I have tried:

adding "//= require stripejs" with and without ".js"

adding entire JS script into application.js file

adding script directly into view - a field appeared but would function correctly.  I can't understand why it works within the snippet, jsfiddle, etc. but not within my application

In the CMD I receive this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Listing with 'id'=stripejs):

app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:131:in `set_listing'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails is using Assets Pipeline to deliver assets.
You can read about it in the official guides [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

There are several ways to import JS in your pages, however, the best approach would be to use the [gem](https://github.com/tansengming/stripe-rails) version of stripe.js.
You can place your custom JS code into your `/app/assets/javascripts/application.*`.

The other way is to bypass Assets Pipeline and drop your assets into /public which is equivalent to the root directory of your server.

Comment: I have "//= require stripejs.js" within my applications.js file.  Still not working -- i also tried without the ".js"

Comment: tried adding the entire JS script into the application file and didn't work.  Can't figure out why it works in the snippet but not the application

Comment: How needed is the stripe-rails gem... shouldn't just the stripe gem work fine for what I have already?  What do you think?

Comment: installed the stripe-rails gem... doesn't seem to work.  I kept getting an error stating "undefined method `secret_key'" ... and would only work when I deleted the stripe.rb file...i added my secret key under stripe_secret_key in my .env file too.  not sure if im doing something wrong.  This should be working tho.  theres probably something very small going on

Comment: It doesn't seem that the root of your problem is a missing JS file, you can check if it is actually being delivered by loading your application in browser, opening developer console and going into the "Sources" tab, which should have all the assets that are being served to the client. The best way to store your secret keys in development is to use secrets.yml which will contain all your sensible data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498357/how-to-use-secrets-yml-for-api-keys-in-rails-4-1 .

Comment: I have the dotenv gem which i have my AWS api keys in within the env file.  Should i not be using that?  Shouldn't that still be working with stripe?

Comment: I am also confused because I have read about the secrets.yml but i never have seen one in any of my apps.  Do I need to generate this myself?  The only YML files i have are storage, database and cable.  I then have a credentials.yml.enc

Comment: I ran the command to create a secrets/yml and looks like i got a note back saying its depreciated for 5.2.   Apparently everything is in the credentials.yml.enc file which i n eed to use from the command.  But I am still wondering about thiis dotenv thing.  why does it work with AWS but not with the stripe

Comment: so in the Source, i have "<script src="/assets/stripejs.self-515a5c43d0bc8c4cedc1b733a487b87626dd61e39c6df9c0033b4c3359d4355b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>" loading... I would assume this is my own stripejs.js file i created myself and not the stripe API... correct? (idk).... so that narrows it down, if im right, that my keys aren't storing correctly.